# C# ListView ItemSelectionChanged Event Multi Select get ONLY last item selected

Tags: c#, events, listview, multi-select

Im using a multi-select ListView in C# .NET 4.5
The issue occurs when selecting multiple items (ie. Shift + End or Shift + Click, etc.) These are just a few examples of many different mouse/keyboard combinations for multi-selecting of course..

This is my event handler for when selecting items in a list:

```
private void lvTitles_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Item.Text.ToString());
    //MessageBox just for testing I am actually running a SQL query here
}
```

My problem is that if I select 500 items the event is triggered 500 times.  The intent is to get that last item the user selected (via keyboard/mouse combinations mentioned above), on and do something with it ... in my case I need to run a SQL query against it.

If I click first on item 0 in the listview it is ok to run the query, then when you shift+end it highlights all the rest, and I want it to run the query only on the last item selected.  Instead it is running on every item in between.

**EDIT: On another note, the event triggers as it unselects as well, in which case it really shouldn't do anything when deselecting.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered performing the action on a button press instead? That way they can also use Ctrl-Click to select any individual items they want?

Otherwise what you would have to do is wait a certain amount of time before firing the action, known as debouncing, you can read a more about debouncing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4517995/984780

I created a class you can use for debouncing:

```
public class Debounce {
    private Action _action;
    private bool _isThreadRunning;
    private Thread _thread;
    private DateTime _runAt;
    private double _waitSeconds;

    private Debounce(double waitSeconds, Action action) {
        _action = action;
        _waitSeconds = waitSeconds;
    }

    private void Invoke() {
        _runAt = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_waitSeconds);

        lock(this) {
            if(!_isThreadRunning) {
                _isThreadRunning = true;

                _thread = new Thread(() => {
                    while(true) {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);

                        lock(this) {
                            if(DateTime.Now > _runAt) {
                                _action();
                                _isThreadRunning = false;
                                _thread = null;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                _thread.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<Action, Debounce> __debounces;
    private static Dictionary<Action, Debounce> _debounces {
        get {
            if(__debounces == null) {
                __debounces = new Dictionary<Action, Debounce>();
            }

            return __debounces;
        }
    }

    public static void Run(double waitSeconds, Action action) {
        Debounce debounce;

        if(!_debounces.TryGetValue(action, out debounce)) {
            debounce = new Debounce(waitSeconds, action);
            _debounces.Add(action, debounce);
        }

        debounce._waitSeconds = waitSeconds;
        debounce.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then you can change your code to this:

```
private void lvTitles_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debounce.Run(5, () => MessageBox.Show(e.Item.Text.ToString()));
}
```

This should work no matter how they select items, it will run your code 5 seconds after their last selection action.

I just wrote this class and did a quick test, a more thorough test would be advised. In any case hopefully it's enough to get the idea.

Comment: I need a range of actions that a user would typically expect such as keyboard Ctrl-A, Shift+End, Shift+Down Arrow... etc as well as Mouse Click + Shift and Mouse Click + Ctrl... and all the other considerations

Comment: When running and making a single selection the messagebox does not popup for 5 seconds..  this would only work if you knew exactly how long it would take to run beforehand...  Im wondering if there is something that can be pulled from this other SO post that me be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666678/how-do-you-respond-once-to-a-user-selecting-a-range-in-a-listview-control

Comment: That SO post definitely looks like a valid option. I suggest since you have the code for both why don't you try them out and see if either works for you. I used 5 seconds as an example You can change to anything you want 1 second, half a second. What it does is that it calls MessageBox.Show(e.Item.Text.ToString()) "X" seconds after the last time lvTitles_ItemSelectionChanged() was triggered.

Comment: Thanks, I will run with it!